# when jquery .html() is used to set inner HTML, .click() event on form button no longer works

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button, onclick

I have a html form which contains a button. This button has a .click() event attached within a js file. This was working fine, until I used jquery .html() to substitute my main page content with the form content. The form shows on the page but clicking the button no longer triggers the event. I am wondering why this is? Code below...

html:

```
<body>
    <div id="mainContent">
        <!-- Visible page content will show here -->
    </div>

    <div id="otherScreens">
        <form id="loginForm">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" spellcheck="false">

            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password">

            <button type="submit" id="signInBtn">Sign In</button>

            <ul id="signInMessages"></ul>
        </form>
    </div>
```

css:

```
#otherScreens {
    display: none;
}
```

js:

```
const mainContentArea = $(document).find('#mainContent');
let onPageContent = $(document).find('#loginForm').html();

$(document).ready(function () {
    mainContentArea.html(onPageContent);
});

$('#signInBtn').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Hello world!");
}
```

I tested changing the .click() event to target #mainContent and it triggered upon clicking anywhere within the div on the webpage, as expected. So I'm not quite sure what's happening with the form button?

(does not seem to relate to suggested duplicate Q)

Comment: _What_ suggested duplicate? If you're reposting then please don't, edit the previous version (in a more constructive way than "NOT A DUPLICATE", everyone thinks that and most people are wrong).

Comment: First, this will create duplicated id's. Second after `mainContentArea.html(onPageContent);` you will not have a form inside `mainContent`

Comment: Also when you say `longer triggers the event`, if you mean this event `$('#signInBtn').click(function (event) {` then yes it's related to `dynamically created item`

Comment: Hi @CarstenLøvboAndersen , so does no longer having a form mean that the button onclick event won't be valid? I thought button tag can exist inside regular div also?

Comment: Every time you set `innerHTML` of an element, it deletes all children elements and adds new once. In your case, you set onclick event listener on a button, but then that button is being overwritten by `$(document).ready()` function

Comment: document ready fires once, not each time you overwrite a part of the DOM

Comment: @riffnl yes, and it fires AFTER onclick event was added...so...

Comment: Sorry, @vanowm I'm new to this. Why does document.ready() override the onclick event listener? When the innerHTML of the mainContent div is replaced with the loginForm innerHTML which contains the button. Even if a new button with a duplicate id is created, shouldn't this also trigger the same event listener, once doc.ready() has been fired?

Comment: @omadume because first you convert DOM into plain text (`onPageContent`), then you convert that text into DOM and overwrite `signInBtn`, which ultimately deletes all event listeners. If you want preserve event listeners, you'll need move the DOM elements with `append()` not through overwriting `innerHTML`

Comment: @vanowm Also, out of curiousity, since html() will create all of the content being set to the referenced element's innerHTML anew (meaning duplicate ids as I understood from Carsten's earlier comment - as I guess it doesn't remove the original loginForm content from the page), is it best to use only classes when using html() to set content?

Comment: @omadume if you are planning on duplicating elements, then yes, don't use IDs. But, depending on context, sometimes it's better and faster move elements around rather than duplicating them. This way you don't need to worry about event listeners. And please, don't use slow bloatware jquery, it doesn't save that much typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your click function in document.ready(function()

Please check below full jQuery code and replace it with your current code:

```
const mainContentArea = $(document).find('#mainContent');
let onPageContent = $(document).find('#loginForm').html();

$(document).ready(function () {

    mainContentArea.html(onPageContent);
    
    $('#signInBtn').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Hello world!");
});
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Kairav, why does the on click need to be moved to document.ready()? what makes it no longer valid on its own, sorry?

Comment: To want it valid by own then you need to use $(document).click('#signInBtn', function(event)..... like this way

Comment: @omadume because `onready` fires with a delay, so if you add event listener before it fired, it will delete all event listeners when it replace `innerHTML`

Comment: not really - you can just use $('#signInBtn').click anywhere you'd like - don't need to be inside the doc ready for that (it's good practise, but you don't need to)

Comment: Thanks @KairavThakar, that worked! But still curious as to why it's not valid in the way of $('#signInBtn').click() ?

Comment: $(document).ready is asynchronous. You are passing a callback function to it so that it logs the fact the DOM is ready. However, the click binding code is being executed immediately after you set up the ready handler, not when the callback has executed.

You just need to make sure you put the binding logic within the ready handler.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite logical (and can be explained). You create an object, wire events to that object - then replace that object with a similar object and you expect the events to magically be wired.. That doesn't happen.

Each time you dynamically add (delete, replace, whatever) elements with events bound to that element, you need the DOM to be aware of that event. Even so, you could even end-up having more than one event wired to the same element.

So let's say (as an example).

```
function replaceElement(htmlContent) {
   $('.mybutton').off('click'); // drop the event handler
   $('#mainContent').html(htmlContent); // replace content
   // add event handler
   $('.mybutton').click(function() { 
      console.log('yup, working again');
   });
}
```

Comment: "wire events"? personally I have no idea what you are trying to explain...and javascript without html also doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Why doesn't javascript wtihout html make sense. The question is clearly about click events which are javascript